# How to Read AT Command Response on Bash Script

Tags: bash, serial-port

I want to send an AT command and read response from bash script. My code is like:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS5 9600
echo "AT" > /dev/ttyS5
timer=0
while read -rs -n 1 c
do
    echo "$c" >> test
    echo "$c"
    ((timer++))
    sleep 1
    if [ "$timer" == 3 ] ; then
        break
    fi
done < /dev/ttyS5
```

then i want to read from test file the response is OK or not. But my scripts output be like:

```
senseless value
O
K
```

when i read that i had some troble. 
What is the best way of checking AT command response?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to remove the duplicate content? It's hard to understand in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

You will be much happier, assuming you can install software in your environment, in searching for a package for communicating on a tty line. `cu` and `minicom` come to mind. Also, you might want to look at `expect` for scripting keystrokes and checking responses.

Using `bash` this way will be quite a challenge.